# How container actually resolve ILogger<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core 2, when we talking about logging, it is enough to just register providers via `ILoggerFactory.AddProvider()` or to use appropriate extension methods. Then you would be able to resolve `ILogger<T>` (without registration of closed `ILogger<>`'s). I'm struggling with a bridge between `ILoggerFactory.CreateLogger<T>` invocation and actual `ILogger<T>` resolution: seems like somewhere magic happens, but I didn't find where.
Any ideas?

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: 'm trying to understand how ILogger<T> resolves without direct interface registration. That's it. No problem yet:)

Comment: Are you trying to find the place in the library where the individual ILogger<T> registrations in the container are taking place?

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko: yes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It all starts in [`ConfigureLogging`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L134):

```
public static IWebHostBuilder ConfigureLogging(
    this IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder,
    Action<ILoggingBuilder> configureLogging)
{
    return hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(
        collection => collection.AddLogging(configureLogging));
}
```

The call of importance here is to [`AddLogging`](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L32). I won't include the entire function here, but the registration process looks like this:

```
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>());
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>)));
```

As can be seen above, [the ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection container allows for the registration of open generics](https://ardalis.com/registering-open-generics-in-aspnet-core-dependency-injection).

Finally, the [constructor](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LoggerOfT.cs#L29) for `Logger<T>` looks like this:

```
public Logger(ILoggerFactory factory)
{
    // ...

    _logger = factory.CreateLogger(TypeNameHelper.GetTypeDisplayName(typeof(T)));
}
```

The rest of the `Logger<T>` class is just a passthrough to the non-generic `_logger`, which now includes the name of `T`'s type.