# Asp.Net Core No service for type has been registered

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have the following two classes

```
public class RepositoryConnection : IRepositoryConnection{

    public RepositoryConnection(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<RepositoryConnection> logger){
    //STUFF
    }

}

public class AuthenticationTokenFactory : IAuthenticationTokenFactory {

   public AuthenticationTokenFactory(ILogger<AuthenticationTokenFactory> logger) {
    //STUFF 
    }
}
```

Here is my Startup.cs

```
public class Startup {

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticationTokenFactory, AuthenticationTokenFactory>();
        services.AddSingleton<IRepositoryConnection,RepositoryConnection>();
   }
}
```

I can successfully inject `IAuthenticationTokenFactory` to controllers but when i try to inject `IRepositoryConnection` i get the following error→

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type　'TrainingCommerce.Accessors.RepositoryConnection' has been　registered.

---

Thanks to comments i immediately noticed my wrongful ways.
I was trying to access at another line

```
var debug = ControllerContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<RepositoryConnection>();
```

Comment: You are likely referencing `RepositoryConnection` somewhere you should be referencing `IRepositoryConnection`. I don't think it's going to be the `ILogger` in this case, but if it is, you'll be able to accept Mike's answer.

Comment: @KirkLarkin thansk for the heads up i just noticed, i was referencing `RepositoryConnection` where  iwas supposed to be referencing `IRepositoryConnection`.OMG that took me hours!!

Answer (score 8):

Try injecting the interface instead of the implementation:

In your sample you inject `ILogger<RepositoryConnection> logger` this is a typo and should be: `ILogger<IRepositoryConnection> logger`.

So:

```
public class RepositoryConnection : IRepositoryConnection{
    public RepositoryConnection(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<IRepositoryConnection> logger){
    //STUFF
    }
}
```

Comment: That's unrelated to the question, since `ILogger<T>` doesn't create or require an instance of `T`, it just needs the type of `T` to set the error "source string" (i.e. used for log filtering and show in which context the logger was invoked). Kirk's comment is on the right track, as you can read from the error message

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the correct answer. Please see @Kirk Larkin's comment

Comment: If you're interested, I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48672938/how-container-actually-resolve-iloggert/48674038#48674038) a while back that briefly describes how `ILogger<T>` gets resolved.